# Have an MVC ActionLink - Need a 'li'

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, twitter-bootstrap

At the moment, on a form, I display a Logout button like this:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Logout", "LogoutUser", "User", null, new { @class = "btn btn-info" })
```

So, it calls LogoutUser in the UserController.

I am trying to add the logout to my menu at the top of the screen, which is built using

format.

But, I am not sure how to convert that ActionLink into a li.

```
<li><a href="#">Reports</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
                    @if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
                    {
                        <li>
                            <a href="~/Controllers/UserController/LogoutUser">Logout</a>
                        </li>
                    }
                    else
                    {
                    <li><a href="#login" data-toggle="modal">Login</a></li>    
                    }
```

How do I get what I am trying to achieve?

Comment: putting your @html.actionlink in the place of your a tag doesn't work?

Comment: Yup, thanks for that! How do I award you the points? Didn't know you could do that.

Comment: I put my comment into an answer.  Many thanks for the points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace your a tag with the

```
@Html.ActionLink("Logout", "LogoutUser", "User", null, new { @class = "btn btn-info" })
```